# Why Run and Debug doesn't work sometimes on remote?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

On remote server, the run and debug doesn't work often on disconnection. On deleting the vscode processes, it works sometimes. And sometimes, I need to remove the .vscode folder and install all the extensions again (a bit hectic often).

Ideally, it should be like this:
[image]

But when it doesn't work, it looks like this,
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Mentioned in the details of the problem.

Comment: Can you solve this problem by trying to use the old version of python extension? I think this is a bug. You can ask the developer in [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the remote installation folder. The default installation folder, `$HOME/.vscode-server` had the low volume. Specifying the folder mounted with larger volume solved the above problem.

In VS Code user settings: `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`:

```
{
    "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {
    "host": "<Path>",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the problem cannot be repreducted, I suggest trying to use the preview version or the old version of python extension.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't resolve the problem :(